# BDD - Does LeanFT support web services testing?

Tags: testing, cucumber, bdd, leanft

We want to work with BDD in our project, we have already a valid leanft licence but I waw wondering if we can automate web service tests using leanft and cucumber?

If not, can you please suggest some testing tools compatible with cucumber and capable of doing web service automation testing?

Thank you.

Comment: I take it you use Java? And what kind of Web Services do you mean?

Comment: Yes, I am using java and I want to automate soap web services

Comment: And can’t you use java for that? Leanft is not for API automation since that would mean reinventing the wheel in that SDK. Java already has means to automate soap web services